# tftpd-hpa + 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, tftp

I installed the tftp server using

```
sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa
```

I then created a directory `sudo mkdir /home/tftp`, changed the owner and permissions

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/tftp
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /home/tftp
```

I then changed the /etc/default/tftpd-hpa file and it looks like this:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/home/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"
```

I then restarted the service:

```
sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
```

however I am unable to upload or download from the tftp server

I verified that the service is running and here is the output of `sudo service tftpd-hpa status`:

```
tftpd-hpa start/running, process 3117
```

Here are the permissions of the directory:

```
sudo ls -l /home | grep tftp
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody  nogroup 4096 Jul  6 16:09 tftp
```

Any ideas?

your help is much appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Is anyone able to help out with this question!? I am sure I am just missing a tiny bit of configuration but I just can't figure it out unfortunately.

Comment: I have few queries 1. How did you try downloading or uploading to the TFTP server ? Any error message you get during testing ?
2. Try some other already exisiting folder like "/home/<username>/Desktop" as the TFTP_DIRECTORY. Dont change the ownership of the folder. Also just verify steps with this [blogpost](http://irfantechinfo.blogspot.in/2013/09/installing-tftp-server-on-ubuntu-1004.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working one.  There is a workaround for the fore mentioned IPv4 issue.

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp" 
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="[::]:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="-4 --secure --create"
```

The `--create` allows users to upload without having to do a `touch`.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem here.
Well, I solved the problem for me :

You can find in the wiki (German wiki!) a chapter about inetd.conf 
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/PXE-Boot openbsd-inetd

The Autor is writing about a bug with IPV4 s.o.
Well, the whole inetd service in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Desktop version) is missing.
I upgraded my ubuntu with the "openbsd-inetd" service and configure the inetd.conf.

`sudo apt-get install openbsd-inetd`

`sudo nano /etc/inetd.conf`

`tftp dgram udp4 wait  root /usr/sbin/in.tftpd /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /home/tftp`

`/etc/init.d/openbsd-inetd restart`

Kind regards
sacki